# Fire a click/tap programmatically on specific coordinate

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-event

is there a way to programmatically (with Obj C) produce a click/tap on a specific coordinate on the screen? I am not looking for a button event/action. Instead, I just want a simple click. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want this programmatic "click" to do?

Comment: @rdelmar: Hi, I am looking for the "click" on a web view area so that the view will respond.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create UITouch object which cocoa doesn't provide by default. take a look at  link below that describe a approach for using categoryon on UITouch and UIEvent.

[Website link](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html)

The approach used in this post constitutes using an undisclosed API — it is therefore illegal to submit applications to the App Store. If you use this code, **only use it in a separate target for testing purposes only**. Do not submit this code to the App Store.